# Post Expirator Plugin translation

Tags: wordpress

I am using **Post Expirator plugin** for expiration of post and pages. My site is in spanish language so i want to display date in spanish. How can i translate the plugin or display the date in spanish in wp-admin have no idea.I tried by adding post-expirator-es_ES.mo and post-expirator-es_ES.po file in theme's language folder and also in post-expirator plugin's language folder but didn't work. Anyone can help me ? Please do let me know.

### I expect output something like this

[image: I expect output something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to translate *post-expirator.pot* file located in *languages* folder of the plugin to spanish.

[Here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-plugin/?ptm=b&utm_expid=3606929-108.O6f5ypXuTg-XPCV9sY1yrw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) is a detailed tutorial on how to translate a plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much @user8230352 i sorted out the problem. I generate new .po file and paste it in theme's language file not in plugin's language file. It works. :)